# Remote Video Editing Server

Tags: untagged

Okay, so here is the dilemma

We have three people, two in California, one in Australia. The person in Australia has several server machines that we all need to use. we are recording gaming videos, and we need to get all of the footage all in one place, and the editor, me, does not have the greatest disk space. In addition to that, our guy in Australia needs to edit as well, and sending 100GB of data from two people to Australia, and then from two people to me is massively inefficient and slow and a disgusting idea.

What would be the best way of setting this up? the most obvious choice is just setting up a remote desktop server that we can all access, and having an FTP server running on it. But would that be the BEST way? is there a better way for us to connect to this server and use only one program? with the lowest latency possible? Also, if the program at all matters, I would prefer Adobe Premier but Sony Vegas would also work, but if we could get a good way of setting this up with any other program i would be willing to learn.
I apologize for this being such a specific question, but if any community could get me a better solution to this than remote desktop, it would be this community.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Microsoft server at your remote location I would look into setting up [RemoteFX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817578%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

I have not used it myself but the idea is that you can utilize the remote server's graphics card during remote sessions. This would allow you to use whatever video editing software you wish and keep the data on the remote machine to be stored and edited in one location.

It requires a bit of setup but this is the only solution I have come across at this time.

UPDATE: (Not enough rep yet to comment.)

Adobe Premiere would need to be installed on the server running RemoteFX.
RemoteFX simply allows the use of the host's video hardware so programs will run normally as if they were on your desktop at home except you're using the remote systems video hardware. Once remotely logged into the server you could run Adobe Premiere like you would on your desktop computer.

Cheers.

Comment: Could we get some information about how to set up adobe premier with using this? I really have no idea. I'm new to remote desktop entirely, and my friend is new to RemoteFX. What would i need to do to specifically make it work with Adobe Premiere

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a NAS system at each location.  Set up replication between them, and after the initial 100GB synchronisation, you're only copying deltas (y'know, the difference between files).

The problem (or rather, the expense) is that you'll want to have reasonably fast storage at each node, so probably SAS disks, with an optional SSD Tier 1 caching layer.

For that kind of performance, I recommend you take your business case to a major storage vendor, ideally one who already has experience in the graphics/video/motion field.

I'd recommend Hitachi Data Storage, or SGI.  They'll be able to figure out a storage solution that will be a good fit for you, and better than something you've hacked together out of coconuts and string.

-- Source? I worked in VFX and know lots about storage.

Comment: I think this idea would be the most professional, but i feel that it is beyond what we need. the whole point is that A) I cant get new hardware, Ive been trying to upgrade my now 6 year old computer for 2 years. However it still runs decent. and B) we really just want to use what we have available. i believe Devin's answer will work, but i have to take a look.